# MongoDB projection: initial setting of all fields to 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection in MongoDB in which document has 73 fields, so when user search for data I want to show only few specific fields. It would be nonsense to set 70 fields to 0 in projection, instead of set all fields to 0 except few specific. I want to know is there a way to do it.

Comment: With mongoDB you could specify the fields that you want to return. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Answer (score 0):

it is easy you can decide which fields to show

{_id:0,wantedField1:1,wantedField2:1,wantedField3:1} this should work for you